# Trying to assign new value to a constant

Tags: c, constants, c89

This is extracted from my module:

**When trying to assign a new value to a constant after it's initialization the compiler issues (only) a warning message.**

This is not correct in C99 but my module seem to be based on C89 could somebody confirm the validity of this statement as per C89.

Comment: just out of curiosity, How you figured out that your module is based on C89?

Comment: Could you please show the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C89` and `C99` seems to both generate an `error` for this case which looks correct, using code in http://ideone.com/x8lXL ;

```
# C89
[~]> gcc -std=c89 test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘A’

# C99
[~]> gcc -std=c99 test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘A’
```

Also note that `clang` agrees to `gcc`here.

Comment: am not sure if I had used the correct code for this, but may be it's the use of pointer and something like that

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the major differences in C99 from C89 and there is nothing mentioned about changes in 'const' keyword.

[off-topic] However, I am not getting the whole C89 standard drafts. Any one know from where I can download it?

Comment: I don't actually have a TC compiler if you have it just compile this piece of code:http://ideone.com/x8lXL

Comment: No, I also don't have TC :)...waiting for some one to update TC compilation results